# Weight of variables in Regression

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, weighted-regression

let's say I have a model with variables Y, X1, X2, X3 and X4. How can I tell how much each variables account for? For example, the model is Y = Bx + Bx2 + Bx3.....

Now if I wanted to look at it this way:

X1 weights about 55% of it

X2 weights about 25%,

X3 weights about 15%

X4 weights about 5%.

is there any way to find how significant each variables is in the model?
Can I do it in SAS somehow?

Comment: How much of *what* do you want to measure? Sensitivity of a particular prediction?  Variance in the response not "explained" by the model?  Rate at which the response changes with respect to changes in the explanatory variables?  Also, please note that there is a standard meaning of "significance" in this context which you might or might not intend in your question: could you clarify what you mean by "significant"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, consider using some formatting, to make things more clear!  You can use $\LaTeX$ formatting to accomplish this.  Here is the link to get to the help page:  [How to use LaTeX here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex)

- $X_1, X_2, ... , X_n$ = covariates
- $Y$ = response variable
- $\beta_1, \beta_2, ..., \beta_n$ = output of regression
- Regression Equation: $Y = \beta_1 \cdot X_1 + \beta_2 \cdot X_2 + ...
     + \beta_n \cdot X_n + \epsilon$

For this model, each $\beta_i$ can be understood in the following way:  If I increase the value of $X_i$ by 1, and keep all of the other covariates the same, then the value of $Y$ will increase by $\beta_i$.  This is the standard way to view this regression.

If you want to "weigh" covariates, you can do this before you run the regression, by multiplying each $X_i$ vector by the desired constant percentage.